# Problem with GlassFish tools bundle for Eclipse and running Glassfish

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, glassfish

I've downloaded the GlassFish-Tools-Bundle-For-Eclipse-1.2 and installed it.
When I run the eclipse contained in the release I'm unable to start the Glassfish server, which arrived pre-configured with the release.
It seems to be looking for the server under c:\ (i.e. c:\glassfishv3\glassfish) when in reality it's under {myDevPlaces}\bundle\glassfishv3\glassfish).

I had the glassfish-v3-prelude installed about a year ago but I uninstalled it.
I've bypassed the problem currently by moving the directory to c:\ but I'd appreciate an actual solution if someone has encountered this.

Thanks,
Ittai

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I'm using a standalone install of GlassFish 3 and the [GlassFish Java EE Application Server Plugin for Eclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/glassfish-java-ee-application-server-plugin-eclipse) (i.e. not a bundle) and everything is working fine.

Comment: Where is the glassfish location defined on eclipse? (For me it's in the preferences->server->runtime) Maybe there is an additional configuration I'm not aware of which uses the old location

Comment: @Ittai That's the only place (Preferences > Server > Runtime) I know. And that's also where I declared the path to my "standalone" GF install.

Answer (score 0):

Please note, As I have observed few days back, GLASSFISH AS 3.1 is compatible and to be downloaded for Eclipse Helios only.

Follow this - http://download.java.net/glassfish/eclipse/helios